# Set fire to the [3rd-party]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Suggesting [3rd-party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party) for burning. It has 1 follower and 111 questions.

Comment: It's also just not a very good tag. Is any library a 3rd party? Where does the 1st party end? In the context of SO it has no use, agree to burninate.

Comment: I agree that the tag is largely useless, but you could at least put a little more effort into your request... a little under 10% of the affected questions have only two tags or less - have you been through to see if you can tidy them up and add more relevant tags? There's no point burning a tag if there's mess left behind, you've achieved nothing.

Comment: @slugster - Sorry you feel that way - this is the first burninate request I've put up, and my interpretation of the "When to burninate" post was that I should raise a Meta post before starting to clean up and re-tag. I didn't want to start removing the tag if the community view point was that it was useful (especially since I have under 2500 rep)

Comment: Was the title meant to be a nod to Snow Patrol? If so, meta points to you, sir.

Comment: @Matt that it is.

Comment: @durron597 yes - you're correct. I saw the question, but didn't read all of it. I thought it only talked about [tag:3rd-party-library]. Is it worth keeping both questions open separately to avoid dealing with two tags in one question?

Comment: The tags in each post are related. 3rd-party needs a clean up before it can be burned, so we should edit in this tag into the other post.

Comment: @HaemEternal You've started the right way, I was meaning that we need more than *"it has x followers and x questions"*. You need to show that you've had a good look through and worked out what the consequences are, frequently a lot of questions will need to be manually tidied up at the same time. In light of the previous linked request I'd say the cleanup work is still ongoing; once the tag is no longer used it will automatically be culled.